# Find comment in beautifulsoap with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and trying to use beautifulsoap to get info from websites. I try to get the previous close price from the website https://www.investing.com/indices/nq-100-futures#comments with the following codes

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.investing.com/indices/nq-100-futures#comments'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
#
datas = sp.find ('div', class_='bottomText')

nums = datas.find('span')
print(nums)
```

I can only get the name of the previous close price instead of the number. I checked the class name I think it should be "span dir="ltr"" but it didn't work in my code. what should I do to narrow it down to the numbers?

Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

For just previous close this code will work

```
sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

datas = sp.find('div', id='quotes_summary_secondary_data')

nums = datas.find('li').find('span',attrs={'dir':'ltr'}).text
```

and in your code if you use `findAll('span')` and print it you will get list so you can get values also from there like this

```
nums = datas.findAll('span')
print(nums)
print(nums[1].text)
```

so main point is you can do multiple ways to understand this i will suggest read doc one time , it is very easy .
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

I have example code too:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.investing.com/indices/nq-100-futures#comments'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
#
datas = sp.find_all('div', class_='bottomText')

## 1. Way
nums = datas[0].find('span', dir='ltr').text
print(nums)

## 2. Way
nums = datas[0].find_all('span', dir='ltr')

for num in nums:
    print(num.text)
```